Github Actions Job got skipped for no reason
I have below github actions code, job 1 got executed, but job 2 always got skipped no matter what if condition i gave.
I've tried below for if condition

github.event_name == 'push' && !failure() && !cancelled()
always() && github.event_name == 'push'
even tried without any if condition

Anyone has any idea why? thanks! been wasting a few hours trying to figure out why but no luck.

name: Monitoring_test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - hway
      - feature-infra/*
    paths:
      - infra/terraform/monitoring/**
      - .github/workflows/monitoring.yml
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - infra/terraform/monitoring/**
      - .github/workflows/monitoring.yml

permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read
  statuses: write

jobs:
  lint:
    name: Lint
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, x64, runners-ap-southeast-2, linux-al2023]
    steps:
      - name: Run super-linter
        uses: super-linter/super-linter/slim@v4
        env:
          VALIDATE_TERRAFORM_FMT: true
          VALIDATE_TERRAFORM_TFLINT: true
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

  job-2:
    name: job-2
    if: github.event_name == 'push' && !failure() && !cancelled()
    uses: xxx/terraform-apply.yml@v2
    with:
      terraform_version: 1.6.6
      aws_region: us-east-1
      environment: production
      oidc_role_to_assume: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/xxxxxxx
      target_role_to_assume: :arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/xxxxxxx
      working_dir: infra/terraform/monitoring/xxxxxx
      terraform_var_files: |
        infra/terraform/xxxx.tfvars
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read



please include log details from problematic run

github actions doesn't give logs. it only says "This job was skipped"

try printing the value of github.event_name in another step in another job. I feel pull request event taking precedence over push event I guess.
run: echo {{ github.event_name }}

Thanks @DayanandaDR for your reply, yep event_name is push

@WZ , looks like problem with your reuseable workflow I guess. please check this workflow trigger points -->  xxx/terraform-apply.yml@v2

Try enclosing the expression in ${{ ... }} i.e. if: ${{ github.event_name == 'push' && !failure() && !cancelled() }}.
